# Determine Bitlocker version with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, bitlocker

I am trying to determine if BitLocker is updated. All I can find on BitLocker is if the service is running as in:

```
Get-Service -name "BDESVC*"
```

Usually the `gwmi -class Win32_SoftwareFeature` will return all applications versions but BitLocker isn't there. Does BitLocker need updating? Is it stored somewhere else?

I am using Win7 64bit PowerShell v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the only option available for checking the version as the application isn't standalone. On Max OS X, it is the same. The version isn't made obvious or available.

Answer (score 3):

After some lengthy searching, I found `manage-bde`. This command works great with the command line and PowerShell. I still am having an issue with pulling just the version number though.

Comment: Yes, manage-bde is the primary command.  To get into one line, we could grep it using findstr.  Have added the same as an answer in case this helps some one.

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps some one now, you can use the following command to extract the required information for your purpose.

> Command

```
manage-bde -status C: | FINDSTR "\<version"
```

> Result

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.15063
```

Please don't forget the '\<' because this is used to filter out the version, else other data containing the word 'conversion' also gets populated.